# How to set default selected value to multi select

Tags: jquery, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I have the following snippet:

```js
function dropdownBis() {
    return {
        options: [],
        selected: [],
        show: false,
        open() {
            this.show = true
        },
        close() {
            this.show = false
        },
        isOpen() {
            return this.show === true
        },
        selectBis(index, event) {

            if (!this.options[index].selected) {

                this.options[index].selected = true;
                this.options[index].element = event.target;
                this.selected.push(index);

            } else {
                this.selected.splice(this.selected.lastIndexOf(index), 1);
                this.options[index].selected = false
            }
        },
        removeBis(index, option) {
            this.options[option].selected = false;
            this.selected.splice(index, 1);


        },
        loadOptionsBis() {
            const options = document.getElementById('recipe_type').options;
            for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                this.options.push({
                    value: options[i].value,
                    text: options[i].innerText,
                    selected: options[i].getAttribute('selected') != null ? options[i].getAttribute('selected') : false
                });
            }


        },
        selectedValuesBis() {
            return this.selected.map((option) => {
                return this.options[option].value;
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```css
[x-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

.svg-icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.svg-icon path,
.svg-icon polygon,
.svg-icon rect {
  fill: #333;
}

.svg-icon circle {
  stroke: #4691f6;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.4/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-paVHVRRhdoOu1nOXKnqDC1Vka0nh7FAmU3nsM4n2FKxOQTeF6crMdMfkVvEsuaOXZ6oEAVL5+wLbQcule/Xdag==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.3.0/alpine.js" integrity="sha512-nIwdJlD5/vHj23CbO2iHCXtsqzdTTx3e3uAmpTm4x2Y8xCIFyWu4cSIV8GaGe2UNVq86/1h9EgUZy7tn243qdA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="w-4/12 pl-4 pr-4">
   <label for="recipe_type" class="mb-1 text-xs sm:text-sm tracking-wide text-gray-500">Type</label>
   <select x-cloak id="recipe_type" required>
      <option class="py-1" value="1">Val1</option>
      <option class="py-1" value="2">Val2</option>
      <option class="py-1" value="3">Val3</option>
      <option class="py-1" value="5">Val5</option>
      <option class="py-1" value="7">Val7</option>
      <option class="py-1" value="8">Val8</option>
   </select>
   <div x-data="dropdownBis()" x-init="loadOptionsBis()" class="w-full flex flex-col items-center sh-64 mx-auto">
      <input name="recipe_type" id="hidden_in_recipe_type" value="" type="hidden" x-bind:value="selectedValuesBis()">
      <div class="inline-block relative w-full">
         <div class="flex flex-col items-center relative">
            <div x-on:click="open" class="w-full">
               <div class="my-2 p-1 flex border border-gray-200 bg-white rounded">
                  <div class="flex flex-auto flex-wrap">
                     <template x-for="(option,index) in selected" :key="options[option].value">
                        <div class="flex justify-center items-center m-1 font-medium py-1 px-1 bg-white rounded bg-gray-100 border">
                           <div class="text-xs font-normal leading-none max-w-full flex-initial x-model=" options[option] x-text="options[option].text"></div>
                           <div class="flex flex-auto flex-row-reverse">
                              <div x-on:click.stop="removeBis(index,option)">
                                 <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4 " role="button" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                    <path d="M14.348,14.849c-0.469,0.469-1.229,0.469-1.697,0L10,11.819l-2.651,3.029c-0.469,0.469-1.229,0.469-1.697,0
                                       c-0.469-0.469-0.469-1.229,0-1.697l2.758-3.15L5.651,6.849c-0.469-0.469-0.469-1.228,0-1.697s1.228-0.469,1.697,0L10,8.183
                                       l2.651-3.031c0.469-0.469,1.228-0.469,1.697,0s0.469,1.229,0,1.697l-2.758,3.152l2.758,3.15
                                       C14.817,13.62,14.817,14.38,14.348,14.849z" />
                                 </svg>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </template>
                     <div x-show="selected.length == 0" class="flex-1">
                        <input placeholder="Type de repas" class="bg-transparent p-1 px-2 appearance-none outline-none h-full w-full text-gray-800" x-bind:value="selectedValuesBis()">
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-gray-300 w-8 py-1 pl-2 pr-1 border-l flex items-center border-gray-200 svelte-1l8159u">
                     <button type="button" x-show="isOpen() === true" x-on:click="open" class="cursor-pointer w-6 h-6 text-gray-600 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                        <svg version="1.1" class="fill-current h-4 w-4" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                           <path d="M17.418,6.109c0.272-0.268,0.709-0.268,0.979,0s0.271,0.701,0,0.969l-7.908,7.83
                              c-0.27,0.268-0.707,0.268-0.979,0l-7.908-7.83c-0.27-0.268-0.27-0.701,0-0.969c0.271-0.268,0.709-0.268,0.979,0L10,13.25
                              L17.418,6.109z" />
                        </svg>
                     </button>
                     <button type="button" x-show="isOpen() === false" @click="close" class="cursor-pointer w-6 h-6 text-gray-600 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                        <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                           <path d="M2.582,13.891c-0.272,0.268-0.709,0.268-0.979,0s-0.271-0.701,0-0.969l7.908-7.83
                              c0.27-0.268,0.707-0.268,0.979,0l7.908,7.83c0.27,0.268,0.27,0.701,0,0.969c-0.271,0.268-0.709,0.268-0.978,0L10,6.75L2.582,13.891z
                              " />
                        </svg>
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full px-4">
               <div x-show.transition.origin.top="isOpen()" class="absolute shadow top-100 bg-white z-40 w-full left-0 rounded max-h-select" x-on:click.away="close">
                  <div class="flex flex-col w-full overflow-y-auto h-full">
                     <template x-for="(option,index) in options" :key="option" class="overflow-auto">
                        <div class="cursor-pointer w-full border-gray-100 rounded-t border-b hover:bg-gray-100" @click="selectBis(index,$event)">
                           <div class="flex w-full items-center p-2 pl-2 border-transparent border-l-2 relative">
                              <div class="w-full items-center flex justify-between">
                                 <div class="mx-2 leading-6" x-model="option" x-text="option.text"></div>
                                 <div x-show="option.selected">
                                    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                       <path fill="none" d="M7.197,16.963H7.195c-0.204,0-0.399-0.083-0.544-0.227l-6.039-6.082c-0.3-0.302-0.297-0.788,0.003-1.087
                                          C0.919,9.266,1.404,9.269,1.702,9.57l5.495,5.536L18.221,4.083c0.301-0.301,0.787-0.301,1.087,0c0.301,0.3,0.301,0.787,0,1.087
                                          L7.741,16.738C7.596,16.882,7.401,16.963,7.197,16.963z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </template>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have by default val5 and val7 selected.

I have tried to add just after the `<template>`

```
<div class="flex justify-center items-center m-1 font-medium py-1 px-1 bg-white rounded bg-gray-100 border">
   <div class="text-xs font-normal leading-none max-w-full flex-initial x-model=" options[option]="" x-text="options[option].text">val5</div>
   <div class="flex flex-auto flex-row-reverse">
      <div x-on:click.stop="removeBis(index,option)">
         <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4 " role="button" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path d="M14.348,14.849c-0.469,0.469-1.229,0.469-1.697,0L10,11.819l-2.651,3.029c-0.469,0.469-1.229,0.469-1.697,0
               c-0.469-0.469-0.469-1.229,0-1.697l2.758-3.15L5.651,6.849c-0.469-0.469-0.469-1.228,0-1.697s1.228-0.469,1.697,0L10,8.183
               l2.651-3.031c0.469-0.469,1.228-0.469,1.697,0s0.469,1.229,0,1.697l-2.758,3.152l2.758,3.15
               C14.817,13.62,14.817,14.38,14.348,14.849z"></path>
         </svg>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But I got the following error :

> alpine.js:1914 Uncaught ReferenceError: option is not defined
> at eval (eval at d.el (alpine.js:144), :3:62)
> at d.el (alpine.js:144)
> at d (alpine.js:131)
> at f (alpine.js:139)
> at be.evaluateReturnExpression (alpine.js:1754)
> at alpine.js:1721
> at Array.forEach ()
> at be.resolveBoundAttributes (alpine.js:1703)
> at be.initializeElement (alpine.js:1628)
> at alpine.js:1612

Is there a way to acheive it using alpine or jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

Alpine JS is a reactive library. Because of this, the logic is tucked away from the DOM, and is somewhat virtual. You can't interact with it directly. You can't append to the virtually generated DOM and expect the same functionality.

### Problem #1

Ok, first issue is that your appended DOM is referencing variables that are only available in the template loop. The variables `(index, option)` are declared within the template. You can't access them outside of the template.

### Problem #2

You can't expect the DOM added outside of the template loop to work with the rest of the virtual DOM. You can manually find the correct index and paste it into the DOM for a temporary fix but this will become problematic overtime.

## Solution

This solution takes an array of values in the constructor and will set these values to the default values of the multi-select.

https://jsfiddle.net/dk2s90cj/

## Food for Thought

This snippet is manually updating and pulling its data from a hidden multi-select field. Why not just use AlpineJS to bind to a multi-select? Why do that work manually?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm pretty new to AlpineJS, so I used a workaround with jQuery